# Handling a filter form along with other get parameters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-tables2

I have a django form with 2 required fields and some optional fields which filters the data presented in a view.

This view uses some `GET` parameters apart from the ones for the filter form and I'm initialising my filter from like `form = MyFilterForm(request.GET or None)` [see (1) in the code below].

I'm finding when my view is first loaded and there are no `GET` parameters this works fine as `request.GET` is falsey so the form doesn't get bound (and therefore we use the initial values for the required fields). If the filter form gets used then `request.GET` gets populated with the form parameters and all works well again. However if one of my other `GET` parameters (namely one used to sort the resulting data table) gets passed without the filter form getting used then `request.GET` is truthy but doesn't have any of the parameters that correspond to the form and so the form gets bound and errors as invalid because my required fields have not been given a value.

What should happen here is that data table should be sorted and the form should continue using the initial ('default') values, just like when it is first loaded.

This is a little tricky to explain and might be clearer with some code...

*I've googled extensively as this feels like a problem other people must have too but haven't had any luck finding anything.*

I'm using [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to present the data in a table for the user but this question is more around the form, the only thing you need to know about the table is that it allows a user to sort the data presented in the table by clicking a table heading - this then adds a GET parameter to the request with the column to sort by I.E `?sort=start_date`.

```
class MyFilterForm(forms.Form):
    date_from = DateTimeField(required=True)
    date_to = DateTimeField(required=True)
    user = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=User.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # dates in correct timezone and at start/end of day
        # initial values set in __init__ so that they aren't fixed at import time
        week_start, week_end = get_start_end_week(timezone.now())
        self.fields['date_from'].initial = week_start
        self.fields['date_to'].initial = week_end
```

And in my view

```
import django-tables2 as tables


@login_required
def view_with_filter_form_and_table(request):
    form = MyFilterForm(request.GET or None)  # (1) The form gets bound when the table is sorted here as request.GET is truthy
    if form.is_bound and form.is_valid():
        date_from = self.cleaned_data['date_from']
        date_to = self.cleaned_data['date_to']
    else:
        # use defaults if not bound or not valid
        date_from = form.fields['date_from'].initial
        date_to = form.fields['date_to'].initial
    user = form.cleaned_data.get('user') if form.is_bound else None

    query = Action.objects.all()

    if date_from:
        query = query.filter(date__gte=date_from)
    if date_to:
        query = query.filter(date__lte=date_to)
    if user:
        query = query.filter(user=user)

    table = MyTable(query)
    tables.RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(table)

    return render(request, 'my_form_and_table.html', {'form': form, 'table': table})
```

---

What I've considered

Checking that all the required fields are in `request.GET` before binding to the form. Apart from being a bit of a code smell because I'll need to instantiate an unbound form to iterate over all the fields and check if the required ones are in `request.GET` to even know if I should instantiate a bound form. The problem here is that if the form is edited and one of the required fields is set to empty by a user I still want validation errors to be shown, aka `This field is required.`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a copy of the request params, removing the `sort` parameter (if exists) and then passing that copy to the form?

Comment: I haven't but it still feels a bit hacky - not dissimilar to my current workaround. I guess I could do
`    if request.GET:
        get_for_form = request.GET.copy()
        get_for_form.pop('sort')
    else:
        get_for_form = None
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently worked around the issue by adding the below code under the code labeled (1) but would love it if there was a cleaner solution.

```
for name, field in form.fields.items():
    if field.required and name not in request.GET:
        form = MyFilterForm(None)  # unbound form
        break
```